# Messages drop on slow subscriber although queue not full / empty

Tags: ros, timesynchronizer, callbackqueue

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Problem

**Setup**: ROS noetic, Ubuntu20.

I have a slow pose estimation node which subscribes to incoming images with a low frequency of only `2Hz`. The images are published by a rosbag with `20Hz`. The bag contains about 800 images (colored, 1280x1024px) , so they should easily fit into the **10k elements queue** of the publisher (`rosbag play --queue=10000`) and subscriber (`message_filters.TimeSynchronizer([image_sub, info_sub],10000`)

I would expect that the subscriber queues the incoming images so that every single image can be processed one after another.
But instead, already after 3 image messages the dropping of messages starts so that in the end ~60% of the messages are dropped.

While debugging the `message_filter.TimeSynchronizer` (synchronizes `CameraInfo` and `Image` subscriber) I could see that the
**image queue is never longer than 1**, while the camera info queue grew proportional to the published messages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390035/messages-drop-on-slow-subscriber-although-queue-not-full-/-empty/) by [belorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/38067/belorenz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-11-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-04**:\

> The problem I am describing here is already solved. Nevertheless I want to describe it and its solution here, because I think it is a common problem for which I could not find any solution online.

posting this here is perfect, so +100 for that, but could you please post the solution as an *answer* instead of a section in your question?

If you then accept the answer, it will be completely clear the issue was resolved.

Right now we only see a new and unanswered question on the index page.

**Comment by [belorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/38067/belorenz/) on 2021-11-04**:
Added an answer but was not able to accept it as correct since I have < 10 points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Solution

While searching for a solution I learned that [message transport in ROS happens with TCP/UDP](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Technical%20Overview#Topic_Transports).
Through this [hint to the TCP\UDP send buffer](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#publish.28.29_behavior_and_queueing) I could stop the dropping by increasing the initial and maximum size of the TCP read and write memory (`tcp_rmem` and `tcp_wmem`) with the help of this [blog post](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tcp-tuning/).

The second number is the initial size and the third number is the maximum size of memory of the TCP buffer in bytes.
I increased the initial and maximum value by adding the following lines to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem= 10240 1258291200 2058291201  
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem= 10240 1258291200 2058291201
```

I choose arbitrary values which simply worked for me (28GB RAM), you might need to adjust these values to your problem.

After saving the file I applied the changes with

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

---

Originally posted by [belorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/38067/belorenz/) with karma: 16 on 2021-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0